# prev/next post links with custom query

Tags: previous-post-link

is it possible to use a custom query instead of taxonomy in previous_post_link()?
Or do I have to build the prev/next links completely custom if I want to use them with a custom query?

Thanks
Stef

Comment: How did you build your custom query?, with WP_Query or something else? If you have any code please add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a custom query you will have to build your own navigation.